# Can I use CloudFlare as a video provider?

Tags: video, cdn, cloudflare

I'm creating a website where people can upload and watch videos. I'm expecting 1000 simultaneous viewers at all times (on average). The problem is that all the CDNs I've looked at charges about $0.06/GB. This means that 0,17 MB/s (720p) x 1000 users x 60 seconds x 60 minutes / 1024 = $36 an hour to host!

Am I missing something?

Over at CloudFlare you don't pay for the bandwith. Does this mean that I can get it really cheap at CloudFlare. Isn't that too good to be true?

Comment: Updated CloudFlare support link: https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/22037282-what-file-extensions-does-cloudflare-cache-for-static-content

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about hosting costs.

Comment: caching streaming video through Cloudflare violates our Terms of Service. Not a good idea.

Comment: No, caching videos is not allowed on Cloudflare. In their Terms https://www.cloudflare.com/terms/ it states: `Use of the Service for the storage or caching of video (unless purchased separately as a Paid Service) or a disproportionate percentage of pictures, audio files, or other non-HTML content, is prohibited.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you're missing the point that Cloudfare will only cache "static and small" files, with these extensions: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-What-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content- as you can see, mp4 and similar are not on the list.

So, assuming most of the cost is bandwith, you will have the same, but a faster website as some resources will be served by cloudfare CDN.

It all depends on how many videos will you have, but usually a dedicated server will offer much more storage (and enough bandwith) for a fixed monthly fee. The problem is that 1000 simultaneous viewers is too much for a single server serving the files.

Comment: How many servers would I need? Is it enough to have one rack?

Comment: BTW, what if I add *.mp4 with a custom PageRule ('Cache Everything')? Wouldn't it cache?

Comment: This answer is outdated. Please see the answer below from damoncloudflare

Comment: Cloudflare has now added mp4 to the list. 
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-What-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-

Answer (score 21):

**UPDATE FOR 2018!**
[Cloudflare now has a streaming video service](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-stream/) to complement their CDN, so that would definitely be the first place to look. But if you just want to host a few MP4 files on your site and save a bit of bandwidth, the following post might still be relevant.

---

Assuming your video content is simply a file downloaded over HTTP/HTTPS (and not streamed over some other protocol) then it appears that CloudFlare might actually support this.

I just tested an MP4 video file on a client's website and it appeared to be cached by CloudFlare correctly.

### My CloudFlare settings page rule:

[image]

### The request (which shows a cache hit):

[image]

Comment: are you sure the ranges header would work, do you see that in your request? not sure cloudflare does that delivery properly, they might just move on

Comment: Good question @RafaelSanches. I haven't tested the `Ranges` header, but it would be good to investigate whether Cloudflare supports this.

Answer (score 14):

The cache everything rule is going to cache it because it is basically doing that...caching everything.

We do not, however, recommend [running streaming content through CloudFlare's proxy](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169706-Can-I-use-CloudFlare-with-a-streaming-music-or-video-site-). People running streaming content on their sites should put it on a subdomain we don't touch.

Comment: The article says *"We have seen sites have performance issues because of the number of connections that streamed content causes when running through the CloudFlare proxy"*.  Can you elaborate on what that means exactly?  Downloading an MP3/AAC/MP4 file within the browser (or a plugin) shouldn't cause excessive connections, should it?

Comment: this is an old post. is this still the case? for videos that are smaller than 5mb?

Comment: I am only using shared SSL on our Subdomain which has streaming m3u8 link but will be happy to know PageRule to deny stream serving  from cloudflare proxy.